# .NET Core with NUnit test

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, nunit

I'm using .NET Core and am creating a unit test.

To do this, I'm running "dotnet new nunit -n tests" to create a project with the first class to test another project.

The problem is: I can run the simple code created with "dotnet test", but I can't code because I'm receiving 'could not be found NUnit' error.

PS.: I'm using [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) (last version).

My .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

***The error:***

> The type or namespace name 'NUnit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: have you tried `dotnet restore`?

Comment: I just noticed that nunit is all simple letters which is different from what I have in my sample project. Try, <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.11.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: @NevilleNazerane yes.

Comment: @Hasitha not work.

Comment: The problem is when I add the reference to another dotnet core console project. Im using this command: 

dotnet add reference ../otherproject.csproj

Comment: I ran the CLI from the question, copied your csproj file to make sure and then ran 'dotnet build'. it works fine. In other words, everything you provided works fine and your issue can't be replicated with just this. So, your issue isn't based on anything you mentioned. Check which line and project the error is actually shown in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using [Visual Studio 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2017) (not Visual Studio Code). It is better to architect a Microsoft solution.

**EDIT**: If you are using Visual Studio (complete version) you can see better the solution, projects and references.

If you are using Visual Studio Code and include new class or files, the reference is not added in you project file (.csproj) automatic. Maybe have another way to do that, but in the moment, I just use the complete version.

Comment: Can you elaborate (so future readers know what to do)? Why does it make a difference to use Visual Studio 2017 instead of Visual Studio Code? Did you do anything else? (Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54171950/edit) (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar), not here in comments).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I updated the answer. I don't know if is you are looking for, but, in the past, I just used the complete version.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue too and was perplexed by it. It turns out the problem is with the solution, not the `dotnet new nunit` project that was created.

The solution is auto-including the sub directory and attempting to build it as source. The directory can be excluded by right clicking the new test project in the solution and selecting "Exclude from Project". Rebuild and the errors go away.

Comment: How do you auto include the sub directory? Can you elaborate (please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55012927/edit) (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar), not here in comments)? At the very minimum with a (specific) link.